# How to specifically whitelist JS libraries which need unsafe-eval

Tags: google, content-security-policy

Is it possible to specify source list values based on the script src. The [RFC mentions](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#enforcing-multiple-policies) it, but I'm not sure about its usage.

For example:

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src *; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self';
Content-Security-Policy:script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com/*';
```

This combination means to disallow `unsafe-eval` everywhere except the Google Map APIs (which needs that).

If not then, it really means that apps have to remove `unsafe-eval` for everything just because a service like Google Maps needs it. I'm not sure if nonces can be used for this type of situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately that is not how it works.

In your example,

```
Content-Security-Policy:default-src *; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self';
Content-Security-Policy:script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com/*';
```

`'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com/*'` are both sources. It is not stating that `unsafe-eval` is allowed on `maps.googleapis.com`, it is stating that `unsafe-eval` is allowed everywhere.

However, as your first header only states `script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self'` this will effectively remove the `'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com/*'` from your second directive. This is the same as only specifying `unsafe-inline`. Each source needs to pass through both policies "unscathed".

Note that you cannot specify a wildcard the way you have. [Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives) for a clear explanation. You need `https://maps.googleapis.com` instead.

Nonces cannot be used to solve this because there is no *static* inline script - eval means it is all determined at run time by the browser.

I would suggest you only output the `'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com` part of the CSP directive on pages that require Google maps, as part of a single header output to the page.

Comment: Ah I see. In my context, the app is a single page app, so I think it might get enabled everywhere.